# Could not resolve project :@react-native-community_async-storage

Tags: jenkins, react-native

I have a jenkins job which build the android apk. when i run the job on mac it is working fine. when i switch to linux i am getting the following error. I am not sure what went wrong.

I have following node modules on both mac and linux. I appreciate your help.

```
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 jenkins jenkins       39 Jan 17 06:32 cypress -> ../lib/node_modules/cypress/bin/cypress
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 jenkins jenkins       42 Feb  3 19:47 env-cmd -> ../lib/node_modules/env-cmd/bin/env-cmd.js
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 jenkins jenkins       40 Feb  5 20:58 eslint -> ../lib/node_modules/eslint/bin/eslint.js
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 jenkins jenkins       36 Jan 17 06:32 jest -> ../lib/node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 jenkins jenkins       35 Jan 17 06:35 mocha -> ../lib/node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 jenkins jenkins       36 Jan 17 06:35 _mocha -> ../lib/node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha
-rwxrwxr-x. 1 jenkins jenkins 35028569 Dec 17 06:36 node
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 jenkins jenkins       43 Feb  3 22:53 node-sass -> ../lib/node_modules/node-sass/bin/node-sass
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 jenkins jenkins       38 Dec 17 06:37 npm -> ../lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 jenkins jenkins       38 Dec 17 06:37 npx -> ../lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npx-cli.js
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 jenkins jenkins       45 Feb  5 08:28 react-native -> ../lib/node_modules/react-native-cli/index.js
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 jenkins jenkins       54 Feb  3 21:23 react-scripts -> ../lib/node_modules/react-scripts/bin/react-scripts.js



05:00:05.096 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
05:00:05.096 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong:
05:00:05.096 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
05:00:05.097 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] > Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
05:00:05.097 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    > Could not resolve project :@react-native-community_async-storage.
05:00:05.097 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]      Required by:
05:00:05.097 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]          project :app
05:00:05.097 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]       > Unable to find a matching configuration of project :@react-native-community_async-storage:
05:00:05.097 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]           - None of the consumable configurations have attributes.

05:00:05.098 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * Exception is:
05:00:05.101 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.TaskDependencyResolveException: Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
05:00:05.111 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
05:00:05.112 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   ... 105 more
05:00:05.112 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionResolveException: Could not resolve project :@react-native-community_async-storage.
05:00:05.112 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Required by:
05:00:05.112 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]     project :app
05:00:05.112 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Caused by: org.gradle.internal.component.NoMatchingConfigurationSelectionException: Unable to find a matching configuration of project :@react-native-community_async-storage:
05:00:05.112 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   - None of the consumable configurations have attributes.
```